# How do i cancel a pending purchase in the App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I have a pending purchase and i just want to cancel it. Its seems that thou may not have an option for this issue.

Comment: Did you make the purchase in iTunes on your computer or via the App Store app on your iPhone?

Answer (score 5):

My experience is that the transaction doesn't take place at the moment you authenticate it.

The download of an app commences, sure, but they don't necessarily take any money out of your account. I saw a week pass until I was invoiced and I'm wondering the same thing the person asking the question is, as I "bought" multiple apps when I had money in my account, then went out the next day and spent what I thought I had left.

I am now constantly being asked to verify my payment information a week later as they never took the money out in the first place, and have restricted my use of the App Store to merely browsing the apps, I can't download or update any of them and they won't allow me to cancel it, it's ridiculous and their customer service is appalling.

Comment: This is somewhat my experience as well. I've never seen a week pass, but my purchases almost always sit for 18 to 48 hours to see if I have other purchases before I get an invoice. I don't know if it's because my account is "stable" in the sense that the same CC has been there for 18 months (typically) and I usually carry between $50 and $200 store credit. I'm sure some percentage of new users get invoiced immediately. Also, when the system is overloaded I bet more people get delayed responses.

Comment: If you want help with the appalling CS - you could ask a new question and I'd answer with several avenues you have to contact them for assistance. No worries if you've already sorted it and needed to vent or express your disappointment. That's fine when it's not overboard.